# Perl How to use DBIx::Class to return data beautifully

Tags: perl, dbi, dbix-class

I'am new to DBIx::Class. Iam using it for an API to retun data from my DB and i want to recreate a SELECT  * FROM table with DBIC. With DBI it worked well for me.
What is the best approach to return data "beautiful"?
I want to return the data in a array of hashes like:

```
[
  {
    id => 123,
    name => 'name',
    ....
  }
]
```

But with `my @rs = $schema->resultset('Product')->all; return \@rs;`. I get not the output i want.
On inspecting the objects with Data::Dumper i get the following:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
              '_column_data' => {
                                  'name' => 'test',
                                  'id' => 123'
                                },
              '_result_source' => $VAR1->{'_result_source'},
              '_in_storage' => 1
            }, 'DB::Schema::Result::Product' );
```

I'am sure i missunderstood the concept of DBIC. 
How can i get the data of all colums only? Thank you all for Help!

Comment: The point of objects is that they provide functionality (methods) along with data (attributes), hopefully in the form of an organized and thought-out set of methods.  So you'd normally browse through docs to find methods that do what you need.

Comment: [DBIx::Class::ResultSet::HashRef](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet::HashRef) provides a thin layer on top of the DBIC ResultSet object that comes handy to output data as Perl data structures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data::Dumper just spills the guts of a data structure. That's the guts of a DB::Schema::Result::Product object which represents a single row of the Product table.

If you want pretty output from an object, you need to ask the object for that. You can call [DBIx::Class::Row](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Row) methods on them. If you want just the row data from the object, use [`get_columns`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Row#get_columns) or [`get_inflated_columns`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Row#get_inflated_columns). They return a hash, so you need to take a reference.

```
my @rows = map { my %h = $_->get_columns; \%h } @rs;
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way I can think is get_inflated_columns method.

```
map {{$_->get_inflated_columns}} $rs->all
```

Consider using [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) and if you really want something beautiful, [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer).

Answer (score 4):

```
my @rs = map {$_->_column_data} $schema->resultset('Product')->all
```

? That said, by convention a field with a leading underscore is a "private" field, likely to be undocumented or underdocumented, or subject to change in future implementations without notice, and you should be wary of accessing them directly.

Since the point of `DBIx::Class` is to translate database rows into objects, you should treat your result set like an array of objects. To downcast it to a hash suitable for use with `Data::Dumper`, you could do something like

```
my @rs = map { { name => $_->name, id => $_->id } } $schema->resultset('Product')->all
```